# jQuery contains method only returns false

Tags: jquery

On https://www.google.ca/ , I'm attempting to see if the body contains a specific class or a specific id ((.content, #main),  which it does).
However, the contains() method only returns false. I don't understand why.

Can anyone explain why this is?

```
var jqry = document.createElement('script');
jqry.src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jqry);
jQuery.noConflict();

$.contains($('body'), $('.content')) #returns false
$.contains($('body'), $('#main')) #returns false
```

Moreover, using vanilla JavaScript selectors, the below code works but not the above, is there a reason for this?

```
$.contains(document.body, document.getElementsByClassName('content')[0]) #returns true
$.contains(document.body, document.getElementById('main')) #returns true
```

Answer (score 0):

From jQuery documentation:

> Note: The first argument must be a DOM element, not a jQuery object or
>   plain JavaScript object.

I tested it but apparently both elements need to be DOM elements:

```
var jqry = document.createElement('script');
jqry.src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jqry);
jQuery.noConflict();

const ele = $("#main")

$.contains(document, ele[0])
```

Comment: That explains why document.body works but not $('body'), is there any way to select a div and then see if that div contains some tag?

Comment: Yes: `$(body).find('<the tag you are looking for>').length`. `length` is `0` so `falsy` when not found and `>0` so `truthy` when found :) - tag just as text without the `<>`

Comment: @Pilan thank you. The reason for the inquiry is I'm attempting to use Cheerio's contains method, but similar to the jQuery attempt, it also returns false. Do you reckon that Cheerio's contains method is running into the same issue due to the reason stated by this thread?

Comment: @Umzd Try explaining your problem more. Since `contains` looks for a specific element, where `find` looks for any matching. Both within the given scope (here `body`).

Comment: I'm looking for an element with some id (ex: #me, there only exists one element with this id) within the body, however, even when attempting to search from the DOM's root, a false bool is returned. Ex: $.contains($.root(), $('#me')) #false is returned. https://cheerio.js.org/#contains-container-contained-

Comment: @Urmzd `$('body #me').length` whats wrong about this? :D